# How do I stream audio from Android to Windows 8 over bluetooth?

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, bluetooth, streaming

I'm trying to find a way to stream audio from my Samsung Galaxy S3 to my Windows 8 Laptop using bluetooth. The devices are paired, but I cannot find a way to stream music. Is it even possible?

Comment: I've decided to keep this question here, but if you'd like it migrated to [android.SE], please let me know. I guess it would be equally on-topic there (although it's more of a Windows issue anyway).

Comment: I think it's a windows thing, I mentioned the phone type just in case it mattered, but I don't think it does.

Comment: What make is your Windows bluetooth adapter?

Comment: @harrymc Let's go with a "Broadcom BCM20702 Bluetooth 4.0 USB Device".  It's popular. :) Since it's a BT 4.0 device it should support most/all the options...

Comment: Close @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 it's BCM2070 3.0 + HS

Answer (score 2):

On my computers (both windows 7 and windows 8 and Galaxy S3) it's done the same way:

1. Turn on Bluetooth on both devices
2. Pair devices
3. Allow Windows to install all sorts of drivers for the phone
4. Connect devices via Bluetooth (you can do it on both S3 and Windows). I can't remember what exactly was it on windows 8, but Windows 7 has a nice button "Connect" with description next to it saying "Listen to audio from your phone through this computer's speakers".
5. Small window pops up on which I can control the audio (Stop, Play, next, previous) with name of my S3 in bar on top.

I remember that Windows 8 has almost the same process, but all I have on me right now is Windows 7.
Honestly saying here that I don't know if for windows 8.1 it works the same. But I assume. It's part of the Bluetooth functionality of the Windows, looks like.
My Laptop is Dell Latitude E6400 (oldie but goodie), with Dell drivers for Bluetooth. No additional software was ever needed.

Comment: Somehow, my computer seems to be missing the needed drivers. It finds the phone, but it doesn't play audio. What am I missing?

Comment: You need to obtain those drivers. Sorry for the harsh reply, but that what it amounts to. Assuming you can connect to your computer simple bluetooth audio device (headphones, BT speaker etc) and they work ok, the drivers is what you need to get.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem here, my PC wouldn't play audio streamed by my Android 5.0 phone. I've reinstalled Bluetooth drivers on my PC and it worked like magic

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please be aware you have posted an answer to a question that is very old. Although there is nothing wrong with doing so, just be aware you may not get a response.