# how to play audio from android to Windows 8.1 PC over bluetooth?

Tags: audio, windows-8.1, android, bluetooth

I am looking for a way to stream any audio from any app or music source from my samsung galaxy s4 to my windows 8.1 computer. All suggestions in similar threads did not work. I can only stream music through certain apps, like vlc directy pro. But this is not what i want. I do not want to just stream music through such apps.

I just want the speakers of my PC to be used instead the speakers of my phone. No matter which app I use.

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stream audio from Android to Windows 8 over bluetooth?](http://superuser.com/questions/517548/how-do-i-stream-audio-from-android-to-windows-8-over-bluetooth)

Comment: none of those solutions work

Comment: Doesn't make it a different question.

Comment: Admittedly the answer on the one I marked as a dupe sucks, so I put a bounty on the existing question to get better answer(s) (hopefully). I know with my 8.1 machine I had to download and install a full Bluetooth stack to get the audio streaming option. Once that was there I just pair and hit something like "allow audio" to start the audio streaming. Unfortunately I don't have it in front of me (or the time) to write a real answer currently.